# Applet MouseMotionListener and Itemlistener conflict?

Tags: java, applet

I want to use applet to draw multiple lines with checkboxes to select the color of lines. Here is my code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class PaintApplet extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener,ItemListener{
    public void init() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        CheckboxGroup colorType = new CheckboxGroup();
        red = new Checkbox("red", colorType, false);
        red.addItemListener(this);
        green = new Checkbox("green", colorType, false);
        green.addItemListener(this);
        blue = new Checkbox("blue", colorType, true);
        blue.addItemListener(this);

        //setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        Panel p = new Panel();
        add(p);
        p.add(red);
        p.add(green);
        p.add(blue);

        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == red)
           System.out.println("red");
        else if (e.getSource()==green)
            System.out.println("green");
        else if (e.getSource()==blue)
            System.out.println("blue");
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        draw=true;
       // X=new Vector<Integer>();
       // Y=new Vector<Integer>();
        X.add(e.getX());
        Y.add(e.getY());
        System.out.println("mouse is being dragged at location (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
        DrawX.add(X.get(lastSize));
        DrawY.add(Y.get(lastSize));
        DrawX.add(X.get(X.size()-1));
        DrawY.add(Y.get(Y.size()-1));
        repaint();
        lastSize=X.size();
        //System.out.println(lastSize);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("mouse is being moved at location (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for(int i=0;i<X.size()-1;i=i+2)
        {
                initX=DrawX.get(i);
                initY=DrawY.get(i);
                finalX=DrawX.get(i+1);
                finalY=DrawY.get(i+1);
                //g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
                if(draw)
        g.drawLine(initX, initY, finalX, finalY);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
           //System.out.println(initX);
           //System.out.println(finalY); 
        }
           super.paint(g);
           //repaint();

    }

    int lastSize=0;
    int initX,initY;
    int finalX,finalY;
    Vector<Integer> X=new Vector<Integer>();
    Vector<Integer> Y=new Vector<Integer>();
    boolean draw=false;
    Vector<Integer> DrawX=new Vector<Integer>();
    Vector<Integer> DrawY=new Vector<Integer>();
    Checkbox red,green,blue;
}
```

However, the problem with the code is that, when the checkbox is correctly shown, the lines can not drawn when dragging the mouse, but when removing the checkbox, the line drawing function is working. Is there any problem when I implement MouseMotionListener and ItemListener?

Comment: Comment out your setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1)); and try again. I believe them when they say GridLayout is sophisticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try putting the two listener inside two separeted threads. 
[Here is how to set up a thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

With this methods the two listeners work separatly and at the same time, so they don't block each other.